# Export multiple sheets in same Excel file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two data tables and **I want to export both data tables as an Excel file having two sheets containing the data of these two data tables**.

```
string myquery = "select * from mytable";
string myquery2 = "select * from blatable";
--making and connection to my db--

try{
   cnn.open();
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myquery, cnn);
   {
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
      {
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    mydt = new DataTable();
    sda.fill(mydt);
         }
      }

   MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(myquery2, cnn);
    {
     MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
      {
      sda.SelectCommand = cmd1;
      mydt1 = new DataTable();
       sda.fill(mydt1);
         }
        }       

      }
```

Comment: This question has a simple example demonstrating how to create an excel spreadsheet with a second worksheet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425746/trying-to-add-multiple-sheets-to-excel

Comment: @jonaglon That answer will require Excel to be installed on the server, which isn't recommended.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid that's a good spot.

Answer (score 0):

Have used SmartXLS for this matter sometime now and its easy to use. Its also fairly documented

> http://www.smartxls.com/csharp/workbook.htm#vworkbook-rw-xlsx